# Randomizing values accounting for floating point resolution

Tags: python, numpy, random, floating-point

I have an array of values that I'm clipping to be within a certain range.  I don't want large numbers of values to be identical though, so I'm adding a small amount of random noise after the operation.  I think that I need to be accounting for the floating point resolution for this to work.

Right now I've got code something like this:

```
import numpy as np
np.minimum(x[:,0:3],topRtBk,x[:,0:3])
np.maximum(x[:,0:3],botLftFrnt,x[:,0:3])
np.add(x[:,0:3],np.random.randn(x.shape[0],3).astype(real_t)*5e-5,x[:,0:3])
```

where `topRtBk` and `botLftFrnt` are the 3D bounding limits (there's another version of this for spheres).

`real_t` is configurable to `np.float32` or `np.float64` (other parts of the code are GPU accelerated, and this may be eventually as well).

The `5e-5` is a magic number which is twice `np.finfo(np.float32).resolution`, and the crux of my question:  what's the right value to use here?

I'd like to dither the values by the smallest possible amount while retaining sufficient variation-- and I admit that sufficient is rather ill defined.  I'm trying to minimize duplicate values, but having some won't kill me.

I guess my question is two fold: is this the right approach to use, and what's a reasonable scale factor for the random numbers?

Comment: Instead of adding a normal distributed noise, I think it  is better for your purpose to add uniform distributed numbers in an interval (-a, a), with a sufficiently small: -a+2*a*np.random.random(x.shape[0],3). This noise has a  variance equal to a^2/3, which is less than 1, for a in (0,1).

Comment: The variance can be chosen arbitrarily for either distribution, but uniform distribution does limit the maximum value which supports the "smallest possible dither" goal.  I'm hoping someone has a good strategy for choosing values of `a`.